# How to get cmd line argument in pytest and set it directly as global

Tags: python, pytest

In python project I have the pytest tests.
I want to get a command line argument (for instance `test_environment`) passed from a pytest line something like:

```
pytest -env "some_test_env_name"
```

but I don't want to pass it to fixture, I just need to get this value from command line and set it as a global variable for whole project (I don't use `test_environment` variable explicitly in test functions).
It's seems to be very simple thing but the only examples I found were related to passing argument through fixtures.

As a workaround I start my tests from a python module where I get arguments I need from command line and after that I run pytest directly from python. However, I'd like to run my tests directly from pytest command line.

Comment: You can always access `sys.argv` but that really doesn't make more sense. What are you *actually* trying to do or achieve that you think setting CLI arguments as a global would be a solution for? Because pytest has [*hooks*](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#hooks) which provide for interacting or interfacing with most of its lifecycle.

Comment: I use argparse.ArgumentParser() to get cmd line arguments but this is in python module, What I need is to have a variable (like test_env) passed from pytest CLI, variable that I could use globally not only in test functions.

Comment: I still have no idea what the actual issue is and it still sounds 100% like [an XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) where you think you know what the solution should be but can't quite get it right, and thus ask for help with the solution you think you should apply rather than ask about the actual issue.

Comment: @Masklinn The question is simple (and probably easy solution in here but this is new area for me) - How to get argument from pytest CML and use it in core (non pytest functions) part of code. 

In `conftest.py` I tried to use:

`def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--env", action="store", default="default name")`

but as I saw that argument is called only for test functions

I tried also a hook like `pytest_sessionstart(session)` but there argparse.ArgumentParser() didn't work